# Find a model's siblings using a relation

Tags: php, yii

This is the table for the model:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `SomeModel` (  
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
  `parent_id` int NOT NULL
)
```

My goal is to be able to query a model with its siblings using:

```
SomeModel::model()->with('siblings')->findByPk($id);
```

Here is my current attempt at the relation:

```
public function relations()
{
    return array(
        'siblings' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'SomeModel', array('parent_id'=>'parent_id')),
    );
}
```

The problem is that I can't find a way to create a condition so that the model itself isn't returned along with it's siblings in the `$model->siblings` array.

Any thoughts would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: you don't want the model returned, only the sibling, but use the model to get the sibling?

Comment: @bool.dev Correct. When doing `$model->siblings` it should return all models with the same parent_id as the $model, except the model itself.

Comment: with your current relation can you get the siblings?

Comment: @bool.dev Currently, when I do `$model->siblings` it returns all of the model's siblings in addition to itself. I need a way in the relation to somehow say `'condition'=>'siblings.id != this.id`'

Comment: actually you can do that, check my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your relation to this:

```
'siblings'=>array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Address', array('parent_id'=>'parent_id'),'condition'=>'siblings.id!=t.id')
```

Edit: Some explanation, in the [documentation for `relation()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#relations-detail), we can specify extra options for the join that takes place and these additional options:

> Additional options may be specified as name-value pairs in the rest array elements.

Plus the default alias for the table is `t` hence use `t.id`.

Edit: from the comments:

Implementing lazy loading, the way you want it, will be tough to accomplish(I don't know how, not sure if possible either), however i can suggest making the current code better, by

1. using [named scopes](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.ar#named-scopes), use a scope when you are doing eager loading, and add the condition `siblings.id!=t.id` in the scope:

   ```
   // add this function to your model, and remove the condition from the relation
   public function scopes(){
    return array(
       'eagerSibs'=>array(
           'condition'=>'siblings.id!=t.id',
       ),
    );
   }
   ```

   Do eager loading with scope:

   ```
   SomeModel::model()->eagerSibs()->with('siblings')->findByPk($id);
   ```

   This will remove the error with lazy loading `$model->siblings`
2. Although the error of lazy loading will be removed you will still be getting the current record, to counter that you can add and use a function of the model which will load the related records without the current one, but ofcourse you won't be using `$model->siblings`, and instead have something like: `$model->getLazySibs();`

   ```
   public function getLazySibs(){
       $sibs=$this->siblings;
       foreach ($sibs as $asib){
           if ($asib->id != $this->id)
               $lazySibs[]=$asib;
       }
       return $lazySibs;
   }
   ```

Comment: Using `t.id` in the condition does not work. The problem is that no join is actually taking place. Seeing the SQL statement might help to clarify: `SELECT siblings.id AS t1_c0, siblings.question_id AS t1_c1, siblings.text AS t1_c2, siblings.position AS t1_c3 FROM qa_choice siblings WHERE (siblings.id!=t.id) AND (siblings.question_id=:ypl0). Bound with :ypl0='36'`

Comment: ok, can you show me your entire relation? because with me, the join is taking place and the code works

Comment: and where are you doing the binding?

Comment: Actually, your answer does solve the specific question I asked. Using `SomeModel::model()->with('siblings')->findByPk($id);` Works, which was my goal. The problem was that I was testing $model->siblings after doing this: `SomeModel::model()->findByPk($id);`. The problem with this is that I can only use the siblings relation when doing a join. Is there a method that will work in both situations?

Comment: thats going to be tough, i'm trying, but in the mean time i found this: [nestedsetbehavior extension](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/nestedsetbehavior). give it a look if you haven't already

Comment: No worries, regardless, you found a way to do what I want, even if it isn't perfect. Thanks for the help!

Comment: made a few changes to the answer, check it. while trying to trace the default function calls yii makes for lazy loading, i couldn't figure out a way to pass `$this->id`, so had to make a new function myself, and modify the result set. You could look into behaviors to try some other method. Thought of using default scope, but that again required $this->id.

Comment: Not bad ideas. I might do a similar hack, and name my relation `_siblings` and then override the siblings property with a `function getSiblings()`. That way I can transparently use the siblings property, but eager load with `_siblings` if needed.